# Grails - Customizing the Scaffolding with extra templates

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, scaffolding

I am implementing new project. I completed one use case, I likes to use scaffolding to generate all other uses cases. if i use generate-all it creates controller, services and views, But problem is,  in my use case, there is 4 more types of classes `<Domain>Search.groovy, <Domain>SearchBuilder.groovy, <Domain>TableDef.groovy, <Domain>DetailDef.groovy` for every use case. So i have to create these four also with generate-all command.

how can i achieve with scaffolding.

Comment: Question is unclear. If scaffolding is used till now then what is the problem with extending the same behavior for new domain classes?

Comment: I modified my request. I hope you can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

A pracmatic approach could be to extend the set of templates (as you mentioned) and additionally to write your own gant scripts. Take a look at $GRAILS_HOME/scripts for some inspiration (i.e. 'CreateController.groovy').